# Asp.Net Core using Kestrel Response being garbled in Nano Server Container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, containers, kestrel

I have an asp.net 5.0 web api app running in: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809

About half the time the response is being corrupted. What is happening is that somewhere in the middle of response some data is injected out of order.

Let's say the response body is

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccc
dddddddddddddd

the response I am getting is

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccaaaaccccccc
dddddddddddddd

So a small portion the aaaa (about 100 bytes) is being injected again into a new location.

Sometimes even the headers are being injected in the middle of the response. So I see

aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccccc
ddddddHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
dddddddd

This only happens when running on kestrel in nano server. I tried running it in a Linux container such as  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:5.0-alpine and it runs fine. I suspect that since its running over a web server (nginx) that the issue is not there. Also, if I access the app running from the host the issue is not there. It happens when I access the app from outside the host.